# Powershell convert list formatted record into table format

Tags: powershell, formatting, text-manipulation

I'm looking for some powershell to convert Listed properties into a CSV or Table, not all records in the list have the same Properties but the "Index" property signifies a new record.

## INPUT

```
Index:1  
FirstName:Bob  
LastName:Smith  
DOB:1/1/1970  
Index:2  
FirstName:John  
DOB:1/1/1971  
Index:3  
LastName:Jones  
DOB:1/1/1972
```

## OUTPUT

```
FirstName,LastName,DOB  
Bob,Smith,1/1/1970  
John,,1/1/1971  
,Jones,1/1/1972
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it through a ForEach and look for Index to create an object, and then add members to it until it runs into Index again, at which point it outputs the previous object, and starts a new one. Then after that you add the last object to the array, and you're set. Then just output to CSV or whatever.

```
    $RawData = Get-Content C:\Path\To\input.txt
$Record = ""
$Array = $RawData | Where{$_ -Match "(.+?):(.+)"} | ForEach{If($Matches[1] -eq "Index"){if(![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Record)){$Record};$Record = [PSCustomObject]@{"Index"=$Matches[2].trim()}}Else{Add-Member -InputObject $Record -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Matches[1] -Value $Matches[2].trim()}}
$Array += $Record
$Props = $Array | ForEach{$_ | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -Expand Name} | Select -Unique
$Props | Where{($Array[0]|Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -Expand Name) -notcontains $_} | ForEach{$Array[0]|Add-Member $_ $null}
$Array | Export-Csv C:\Path\To\File.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit:** I realized my first answer had a pitfall where if the first record is missing a field (say, there was no LastName) that it wouldn't display that field for any of the following records. I have rectified that by getting a list of all unique fields from each record, and adding any missing ones to the first record with a null value.

**Edit2:** After looking at both Patrick's and my answers I realized that his runs much faster, so have created a modified version combining both our answers. Some technique of object creation taken from his, and line parsing taken from mine:

```
$RawData = Get-Content 'C:\temp\input.txt'
$Record = ""
$Array = @()
$Props = $RawData -replace "(.+?):.*","`$1"|select -Unique
ForEach($Line in $RawData){
    $Line -Match "(.+?):(.+)" | Out-Null
    If($Matches[1] -eq "Index"){
        If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Array[0])){$Array = @($Record)}else{$Array += $Record}
        $Record = ""|Select -Property $Props
        $Record.Index = $Matches[2].trim()
    }Else{
        $Record.($matches[1]) = $Matches[2].trim()
    }
}
$Array | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\export2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Many thanks. Answered the question exactly as specified but of course the source data I get is "changeable" (I don't control it). Removing lines not matching ":" was a masterstroke.

Comment: Also use of Match instead of Split was another masterstroke, some of the DOB values use ":" instead of "/".

Comment: You may want to look at my last edit. It will run considerably faster unless you have extraordinarily large files (several megabytes if not hundreds). In my tests of roughly 4.5k lines it ran about twice as fast as my first script, and produced the same results. I also took care of extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

An other example.

```
$arrInputFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\input.txt"
$strCSVExportPath = "C:\temp\Export.csv"

$arrCSVHeader = @()
Foreach ($strLine in $arrInputFile) {
    If ($arrCSVHeader -notcontains $strLine.Split(":")[0]) {
        $arrCSVHeader += $strLine.Split(":")[0]
    }        
}

$arrCSVOutput = @()
$objCurrentIndexBlock = $null
Foreach ($strLine in $arrInputFile) {    
    If ($strLine.Split(":")[0] -eq "Index") {
        If ($objCurrentIndexBlock -ne $null) {
            $arrCSVOutput += $objCurrentIndexBlock
        }

        $objCurrentIndexBlock = "" | Select-Object -Property $arrCSVHeader
    }

    $objCurrentIndexBlock.$($strLine.Split(":")[0]) = $strLine.Split(":")[1].Replace(" ",$null)

}
$arrCSVOutput += $objCurrentIndexBlock

$arrCSVOutput | Export-Csv -Path $strCSVExportPath -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Many thanks. Very readable for a PS amateur. Credit also to TheMadTechnician for removing lines not matching ":".